# VirtualBox says "No bootable medium found!"

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, iso-image

I downloaded the latest `mu microsoft hpc pack 2008 r2 with service pack 2 x86 x64 dvd 709909.iso`.

Both VMWare Workstation and Oracle's VirtualBox give me an option to select an ISO file . When I do this, I get "No bootable medium found!".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What ISO file is that exactly? Where did you get it from?

Answer (score 0):

```
Rule #1: Don't trust random files you find on the internet.
```

I'm assuming you downloaded whatever [this](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/27790-Microsoft-HPC-Pack-2008-R2-with-Service-Pack-2-%28x86-and-x64%29) forum page is referring to.  You won't be the last person who falls victim to not following Rule #1.

If you are in fact looking for the Microsoft High Perfomance Computing Pack 2008, have you tried looking at and downloading it from Microsoft themselves?

They even have a 180 day trial that you can play with.

Check out their [Try Windows HPC Server Today](http://www.microsoft.com/hpc/en/us/trial/what-is-hpc.aspx) page, on the right hand side there is a [Download Trial Software Link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4b013794-f6fc-4070-b769-9acd0c140ca9&displaylang=en)